# How to use specifically use HTTP (not HTTPS) proxy with python requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, web-crawler, proxies

I just want to know how to use **HTTP proxies** with python requests because valid HTTPS proxies are hard to find.

Code:

```js
import requests

proxy = "85.208.210.33:8085"

proxies = {
    "https": "http://" + proxy,
    "http": "http://" + proxy
}

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.96 Safari/537.36"}
r = requests.get("https://httpbin.org/ip", headers=headers, proxies=proxies, timeout=3)
print(r.status_code)
```

Comment: What problem do you face though? If you just want to use HTTP Proxies, Remove the "https" key from your proxies dictionary. Beware, You can only visit non-ssl websites.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: first you would have to find working proxy and next you would have to check what urls it use. If you would use `TOR Network` (installed with [TOR Browser](https://www.torproject.org/)) then you would need `proxies = {"https": "socks5://localhost:9050", "http":  "socks5://localhost:9050"}`